# My cat bites my hand mildly after hearing cats in my phone

Tags: cats, behavior

One of my two cats called Chilli happened to bite my mother's hand, but it wasn't anything to be concerned about. It was a mild bite. My mother was trying to see how our cats would react after hearing cats meowing in a video on her phone. Chilli came towards her and bit her hand, then left.

Around 2 months after I happened to be doing the same thing as my mother did. I played the same video on my phone that was played two months before, and I got the same result. Chilli bit my hand very lightly and then retreated as soon as the video ended.

What does this mean? Is she not fond of the meowing?

Also, this is the specific video:
[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3U0udLH974)

Comment: A light bite is usually more of a grab than a bite. What it means to the cat can be really hard to determine without all the context, though; I don't know the cat, don't know the details of the situation, and wouldn't attempt to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two cats in the video are talking to each other, the title is "The two talking cats".  They seem to like each other, as there is grooming at the end.

While I don't speak cat, it seems to be a romance or some other kind of 'chic lit' video.

Your cat is putting her mouth on your hand to communicate her thoughts about the story you are sharing with her.